# Separate line in HTML search bar form from Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

B have a bootstrap search bar form in my HTML, but i want to make another one but in the same bar with line separating them, how i can implement that?

[image: This is the bootstrap search bar]

```
<form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="I'm Looking For.." aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
```

this is the search bar i have

---

[image: The desired search bar e.g.]

and this looks like what i want to do, two search bars merged and separated using a little standing line

it would be cool if i could do this using only html without css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use bootstrap you can go and would refer form
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/input-group/
and get plenty of information  you want to make a input group

Comment: Tbh i didn't know it's named input group, thanks alot